# ansible uri module json code fails with unwanted escape chars

Tags: curl, ansible, char, escaping, uri

if i use the following code:

```
  - name: DirectAdmin | Delete TXT record if existing challenge_code IS found
    uri:
      url: 'https://{{ server }}/CMD_API_DNS_CONTROL?json=yes'
      method: POST
      body_format: raw
      body: '{"domain":"{{ domain }}","json":"yes","action":"select","delete":"yes","affect_pointers":"no","txtrecs0":"name={{ old_record }}&value={{ old_value }}"}'
      headers:
        Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      url_username: "{{ user }}"
      url_password: "{{ password }}"
      force_basic_auth: true
      timeout: 15
    register: result
```

ansible super verbose shows the following request:

`"body": "{\"domain\":\"produtchracing.nl\",\"json\":\"yes\",\"action\":\"select\",\"delete\":\"yes\",\"affect_pointers\":\"no\",\"txtrecs0\":\"name=_acme-challenge&value=\"_RE9fHGBVjk7FcuufUk0LKU4v-KR1RONUMQSrLAljto\"\"}",`

The command fails then with error:
`"result": "_acme-challenge TXT  did not exist\nWarning from named-checkzone:\n\n",`

if i however do the same thing using curl from the command line, e.g.

`curl -s --max-time 15 --user xxx:yyy 'https://produtchracing.nl:2223/CMD_API_DNS_CONTROL?json=yes' --data-raw '{"domain":"produtchracing.nl","json":"yes","action":"select","delete":"yes","affect_pointers":"no","txtrecs0":"name=_acme-challenge&value=\"_RE9fHGBVjk7FcuufUk0LKU4v-KR1RONUMQSrLAljto\""}' --compressed`

it works

if i use command with curl code the code also gets added with the unwanted escape chars and it also fails

How can i provide the correct code to curl or uri module ??

Ps. code is to used to control the api from directadmin

expected same result as by using the curl command from command line

Comment: "`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`" looks like json to me.   `body: '{ ... }'`" don't try to format your own json.  It's a huge waste of your time.  Instead provide the data as as `dict` and then `| to_json` filter